# Why two identical generic types give different results?

Tags: typescript

Please, help me to figure out the logic of the TS compiler here.
I don't see any strong difference between LookUp and LookUpWrong and don't understand why LookUpWrong always returns `never`.

```
type LookUp<U, T extends string> = U extends { type: string } ? U["type"] extends T ? U : never : never
type LookUpWrong<U extends { type: string }, T extends string> = U["type"] extends T ? U : never

type Animal = { type: 'dog' } | { type: 'cat' }

type ValidResult = LookUp<Animal, 'dog'> // { type: 'dog' }
type WrongResult = LookUpWrong<Animal, 'dog'> // never
```

Comment: Look up “distributive conditional types”; your first example distributes over unions in `U` and the second one doesn’t.

Comment: @jcalz, isn't `U["type"]` in the second example resolves as union `'dog' | 'cat'`?

Comment: Have you looked up “distributive conditional types”? I’m on mobile now so I can’t write up a code example.  Unions are treated differently when the conditional type is distributive from when it’s not.  And distributive conditional types only happen when the checked type is a plain type parameter.  It’s documented and there are other SO questions about it.

Answer (score 1):

I have less know how of typescript but gave it a shot on the playground based on @jcalz input.

From what I can see is that :-

```
type LookUp<U, T extends string> = U extends { type: string } ? U["type"] extends T ? U : never : never
type LookUpWrong<U extends { type: string }, T extends string> = U extends { type: string }? U["type"] extends T ? U : never : never

type Animal = { type: 'dog' } | { type: 'cat' }
type Banimal = { type : 6};

type ValidResultLookUp = LookUp<Animal, 'dog'> // { type: 'dog' }
type ValidResult2LookUpWrong = LookUpWrong<Animal, 'dog'> // {type:'dog'}

const obj:ValidResultLookUp = {type:'dog'};
const obj2:ValidResult2LookUpWrong = {type:'dog'};;

type invalidResultLookUp = LookUp<Banimal,'dog'> // doesn't give error since it's just U which Banimal satisfies
type invalidResultLookUpWrong = LookUpWrong<Banimal,'dog'> // gives error before hand since Banimal doesn't extend {type:string}
```

If you reformat `LookUpWrong` same as `LookUp` with the additional `U extends {type:string}` conditional check as I did above, both the types when used to build `ValidResultLookUp` and `ValidResult2LookUpWrong` work as expected because the `Animal` type satisfies the extends `{type:string}` bit of the conditional.
Introducing that conditional check to `LookUpWrong` kicks in the [distributive conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) property and instead of below :-

`type someType = 'dog' | 'cat' extends 'dog' ? 'desiredType' : never;`

`someType` will be `never`

the below happens :-

`type someType = 'dog' extends 'dog' ? 'desiredType' : never;` and also the `cat` bit happens but is not relevant since `dog` extends `dog` due to distribution makes the conditional truthy and we get `desiredType`.

Now consider `Banimal` which is `{type:6}`. `LookUp` in this case will not give you an error when building `invalidResultLookUp` since `U` doesn't extends on `{type:string}` unlike `LookUpWrong` which does (the generics portion).

So you still need that conditional check(for distributive conditional effect) in case of `LookUpWrong` but it prevents wrong assignment of type when building another type due to additional `U extends {type:string}` safeguard.

Here is the playground [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=16&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAMg9nA1gVTAHmQGigFShAD2AgDsATAZyguACcBLEgcwD4oBeKZfI0yqAN5RQkAFzU6jJlAC+UAPxcA2gCIREFQF0exclTyLu4khABuEWlGNmLAKHWwEKMAHVacZhh18qQ9eJoGZllsPEJdfkCpNk5ucJ9BYXAIAMlgmUNVdS1vPVwFLisoE3NLa1Lbe2SoAEESegBbAEMAGw5E-ygAcjI4Ji7ZKAAfDuTxLoBjJuABmSrIKAAhJvrmts4-avEANhkAbkqHADVW+jIAJQgKAFcW4HgkVHaH5zQ6xtbsHr6utgB6P6jMTdXr9WTzaAnFpnS43O4AJheqDcHmknCRrncnneay+oN+UABgn8336c1sEw8NCgcAARgArURQmFXW73JxPDYk-H7ClU4A0hnwpmnC6shEYlHBLljUldfYHCFQRimUWwtkY54c9DLVafOX-QG9K4kLoCpj0cz4WjuSwURgTaD0GZUenXancADuAAt6BNvUsVh82hRpvQKAAzehXJUqtXi9mPTGorVJqVMNC64OYA2EwEW8xUCy2qC0iARuC0aDelZkagO6BZtZQY0UU0C+LkYljKLMcm2IA)